# How to apt-get install libncurses5-dev

Tags: raspberry-pi, http-status-code-404, apt, raspberry-pi4

I want to install libncurses5-dev on my Rasberry pi 4.
But after the 404 error, I tried apt-get update and upgrade, but it still hasn't been fixed.
What should I do?

and here's my information "uname -a" told me.

Linux raspberrypi 4.19.57-v7l+ #1244 SMP Thu Blah, blah, blah armv7l GNU/Linux

and sources.list

deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
#Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi

Answer (score 0):

Try with `apt-get install libncurses-dev`.

Accordingly with https://packages.debian.org/buster/libncurses5-dev version 5 is no longer available on official repos. See https://packages.debian.org/buster/libncurses-dev.